# How does WebChromeClient.onJsAlert() show system dialog?

Tags: android, android-webview

If H5 show an alert in android webview, we can override `WebChromeClient().onJsAlert()` to show android dialog like this:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
    }

});
```

I would like to know where to display the dialog, and how to dismiss it in code.

Answer (score 0):

You would simply do it in that method

1. Create and show the `AlertDialog`
2. Don't forget to call `result.confirm()` or `result.cancel()` when the *dialog* is dismissed in the *positive* or *negative* buttons `OnClickListener` respectively.
3. Use `return true` to show you are handling the JS alert.

Something like this:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, final String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        result.confirm();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        result.cancel();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();

        return true;
    }
});
```